Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)
I am trying to build a CNN model in R to classify between three types of images. The library in R seems to create a Python virtual environment and make calls to it for some tensorflow tasks. My R code is
library(keras)
library(EBImage)
library(stringr)
library(pbapply)
# Set image size
width <- 50
height <- 50

extract_feature <- function(dir_path, width, height, labelsExist = T) {
  img_size <- width * height
  
  # List images in path
  images_names <- list.files(dir_path)
  
  if (labelsExist) {
    # Extract class labels from filenames
    class_labels <- unique(basename(images_names) %>% str_extract("^[^_]+"))
    
    # Create the key vector
    key <- setNames(as.integer(seq_along(class_labels)), class_labels)
    
    # Set labels
    y <- key[basename(images_names) %>% str_extract("^[^_]+")]
  }
  
  print(paste("Start processing", length(images_names), "images"))
  
  # Process images
  feature_list <- pblapply(images_names, function(imgname) {
    img <- readImage(file.path(dir_path, imgname))
    img_resized <- resize(img, w = width, h = height)
    grayimg <- channel(img_resized, "gray")
    img_matrix <- grayimg@.Data
    img_vector <- as.vector(t(img_matrix))
    return(img_vector)
  })
  
  feature_matrix <- do.call(rbind, feature_list)
  feature_matrix <- as.data.frame(feature_matrix)
  names(feature_matrix) <- paste0("pixel", c(1:img_size))
  
  if (labelsExist) {
    return(list(X = feature_matrix, y = y))
  } else {
    return(feature_matrix)
  }
}

# Prepare the data
#train_data <- extract_feature("C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/Training/train/", width, height)
#write.csv(train_data,'C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/train_data.csv')
train_data <- read.csv('C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/train_data.csv')
X_train <- train_data$X
# Convert labels to one-hot encoding
unique_labels <- unique(train_data$y)
y_train <- sapply(train_data$y, function(x) {
  label_vector <- rep(0, length(unique_labels))
  label_vector[which(unique_labels == x)] <- 1
  return(label_vector)
})
y_train <- t(y_train)

#test_data <- extract_feature("C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/Testing/test/", width, height, labelsExist = F)
#write.csv(test_data,'C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/test_data.csv')
test_data <- read.csv('C:/Users/aryaj/OneDrive/Desktop/project 6/data/test_data.csv')
X_test <- test_data

# Define the model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_dense(units = length(unique_labels), activation = "softmax")

summary(model)

# Compile the model
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

# Train the model
history <- model %>% fit(
  x = X_train,
  y = y_train,
  epochs = 20,
  batch_size = 100,
  validation_data = list(X_test, y_test)
)

# Evaluate the model
score <- model %>% evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(paste("Test loss:", score[1]))
print(paste("Test accuracy:", score[2]))

# Plot the training history
plot(history)

And the error I am getting is like this
> model %>%
+   layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
+   layer_flatten() %>%
+   layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu") %>%
+   layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
+   layer_dense(units = length(unique_labels), activation = "softmax")
2024-04-06 14:59:23.781982: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: <Sequential name=sequential, built=False> (of type <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'>)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

I tried to change the model building step as following
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_dense(units = length(unique_labels), activation = "softmax")

But even this one keeps giving the same error.
